# How to make solution file from separate aspx and aspx.cs files?

Tags: asp.net

I'm new in ASP.NET. I have three .aspx file and their associated .aspx.cs files in a folder. These three screens are parts of the project that I can run them in browser.

1. How can I get the project files (.csproj) from aspx and aspx.cs files?
2. how can I group these three aspx and aspx.cs files under one solution in Visual Studio? Basically, I need the solution file of the project but I have just aspx and aspx.cs files. Is there anyway to upload these files in visual studio under a solution and get the solution file? plz help

Comment: Create new web application and add your all aspx and aspx.cs files as an existing items to newly created solution

Comment: Appreciate Rahul, when I open visual studio Express 2013 for desktop, in the new project section it gives only these options:

1. Windows Form Application
2. WPF Application
3. Console Application
4. Class Library
5. Template MVC5 & WCF & ASP.NET Identity

but there is no web application. What can I do? Does VS express for desktop support web applications?

Comment: [Create the Project using Visual Studio Express](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create-the-project)

Comment: You need to have visual studio Express 2013 for Web to do that.

Comment: Thank you guys, I created a web application in VS 2013 for web, but when I'm clicking add existing item to the new solution, both options (new website and existing website) are inactive. why I can't add aspx and aspx.cs files under a new solution?

Answer (score 1):

Templates-->Visual C#-->Web-->ASP.NET Empty Web Application

[image]

Comment: Here you no need to use import option ,just paste your aspx, aspx.cs file under the root of the web application then set your start up page ,it will run.